# getting xmlhttp status 401 in forefox while making ajax call to windows authenticated WCF service from javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call windows authenticated WCF service from javascript, but I am getting xmlhttp response status 401, which is unauthorized access. I have already written code for allowing cross domain access. It works with Forms authentication but the problem occurs when we make it windows authenticated. Please help !

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be related to not passing your NTLM authentication on to the site.

Try this:

1. In Firefox type in about:config in the address bar
2. In the filter field type `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`
3. Double click the name of the preference you searched for above.
4. Enter the URL(s) of any sites that you'd like to pass NTLM authentication tokens to. Like:

   `http://myinternal.site.com,https://intranet.companysite.com`
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for the about.config key: `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`